# Generating nested part of a glob pattern using command substitution

Tags: zsh

Let's start with a simple filename generation example:

```
echo (xx|yy|zz)*.txt  # Example 1
```

This lists all txt-files starting with xx or yy or zz. Now let's generate those alternatives dynamically using command substitution; I'm using `echo` here just for illustration of where I'm heading to; in a "real world" example, this would of course be some program:

```
echo $(echo '(xx|yy|zz)')*.txt  # Example 2
```

This would work like above. Now comes the tricky part: The command substitution should only supply PART of the list of alternatives:

```
echo ($(echo 'xx|yy')|zz)*.txt  # Example 3 (does not work)
```

This would not work anymore: It would find files starting with zz, but not those with yy. I guess Zsh is searching for files starting literally with `xx|yy` here.

We can get it working, if we use an auxiliary variable:

```
list=$(echo 'xx|yy')
echo (${~list}|zz)*.txt   # Example 4
```

Now to my question:

Is it possible to achieve the effect of example 4, without using a temporary variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
echo (${~"$(echo 'xx|yy')"}|zz)*.txt
```

Note the quotes around the command substitution as `zsh` does perform word splitting, if not globbing by default upon command substitution, which can come handy in things like:

```
echo (${~${(j:|:)$(cmd)}}).txt
```

to join the words in the output of `cmd` with `|` and interpret it as a glob. See also the `b` parameter expansion flag if you don't want those words to be treated as patterns themselves:

```
echo (${~${(j:|:)${(b)$(cmd)}}}).txt
```